# Source Code Protection

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When you compile a program to publish with Visual Studio 2010, does that have any advanced methods to keep your program being decompiled to source code? Are there any methods you would use to encrypt yoursource code before compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio by default does not apply any form of enhancements nor modify the compiled binaries other than chosen optimization setting.
There are however protectors you can make use of.
Remember UPX?
Well upx is still a very viable method of encrypting your binaries altough of course it all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's really no way to prevent a managed assembly from being decompiled back into source code. The best you can hope for is [obfuscation](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/), which can do quite a good job of making the decompiled code hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 comes with Dotfuscator community edition which will obfuscate your code to a point making it harder to read once decompiled. The only real choice is to encrypt your code if you need the absolute best security. You might want to check out the paid edition http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview to see if it suits your needs and budget

Answer (score 1):

You can use obfuscators which employ various techniques like class/method name renaming, string encryption, method call hiding, etc. Even if someone were to view your code in a disassembler, he would not be able to make any sense out of it.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developers of [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm)

Answer (score 0):

VS and any other good compiler make optimalizations. Solely these optimalizations are often enough to make your application resist reverse engineering attempts.

This will not encrypt constants in your program so `mypass` will still be found as `mypass` in the binary. You **need** an encryption program for that.

Alas I have no idea what the good and bad encryption programs are for binaries so I won't suggest any.

Answer (score 0):

Best protectors are confuser ,engima and themida

Comment: A little more explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

Wibu Systems offers a solution that encrypt the binary files which will preventing reverse engineering.

https://www.wibu.com/uk/products/protectionsuite/axprotector-ip-protection.html